# Scrolling on fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have fixed header with the structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
        <ul style="width:932px;height:700px;margin-left:-430px;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x: hidden;">
```

When I make the browser smaller than the contents of the `<ul>`, the vertical scroll bar is not showing. Any ideas?

Comment: @Roysh I have closed them, just have not copied everything. inline or not,  stop trolling.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with responsive CSS, see more at http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

In your case, you put new "class" or "id" for your "div" tag, then you just @media (see above instruction) for your resolution case and make "display:none" for your element.